# How can I change a wordpress custom post back to a standard post?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have inherited a legacy wordpress installation which has a complex template with a couple of custom post types.

I want to migrate it to a simpler theme and convert all the custom post types back to regular posts.

I have gone into the wp_posts table and changed the values in the post_type column from "product" or "service" or whatever back to "post" and the posts in question now load into the template, but they don't show up in the list of posts in the admin page.  If I load the editor on another post, and change the ID in the url bar to one of my would-be normal posts, they will load up and I can edit them, but I just can't make them show up in the posts list.

Is there somewhere else I need to change things to make Wordpress see them as standard posts?

Comment: Looking at `wp_posts`, is `post_status` set to `publish`?

Comment: 'publish' should not affect it, but worth setting just in case... perhaps it's the 'guid'. Just look at the format of a working post's guid and the the custom ones to match. Perhaps even just for the heck of it set the post_parent to 0. Maybe in post_meta it needs a category assigned? Clearly I am just guessing here.

Comment: The Guid is there just for external purposes (provide a unique id for rss) and is never used internally. To me, it looks like a badly configured cache plugin, that caches also the admin and is not updated. 

If you see no chache plugin in the admin, have a look at htaccess and wp-config.php, these plugins leave tracks in these files.